# Is there a two-computer, multiple-port USB or KVM switch with *individual buttons* for each USB device?

Tags: usb, power-supply, kvm, hub

I operate a two-computer setup with multiple displays and a *plethora* of USB devices. I have a [pretty excellent KVM switch](https://www.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/2-Port-Dual-DisplayPort-USB-KVM-Switch-with-Audio-and-USB-20-Hub~SV231DPDDUA), that I'm generally very happy with; but I often need to switch the keyboard/mouse separately from the monitor. (i.e., I don't actually use the ‘K’ and ‘M’ in my KVM .)

At the moment, I have [a four-port USB-switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00Y3CTDAY) that I'm using to augment that. In particular, it has:

1. Separate power-supply (weirdly, *also* over USB; but hey, whatever),
2. Four output ports,
3. USB-3.0 support,
4. and **a wired remote**, so I can control it from the front of my desk.

The problem I'm still suffering, though, is a subset thereof: right now, my shared display has independent control through the KVM; but my keyboard, mouse, DAC/speakers, and smartcard authentication setup (`<3` Yubikey!) are all linked together. This means that anytime I want to type some text into my PC, I hit the remote's button under my desk, and … my music cuts out, my Mac locks itself (because I've ‘removed’ my smartcard), and Windows beeps a bajillion times as it briefly recognizes new devices. `ಠ_ಠ`

So, what I *really* want, I've belatedly realized, is a USB switch with:

1. At least two host-side USB 3.0 connections,
2. at least four **individually-switchable** USB 3.0 ports for devices,
3. if possible, an independent power-supply, not bus power,
4. if possible, maintained *power* to the switched devices, regardless of what they're currently connected to,
5. and if possible, some sort of remote head — or most preferably, software control from the hosts (I'd love to be able to hack together *a key combination* that switches devices!), so I can keep the dang thing hidden away behind my desk.

Cost is no object, this is for my primary workstation.